# How to get data from config.xml of a module

Tags: module, magento-1, xml, configuration, core-config-data

In the module **A** I need to get some data from file *config.xml* of modules **B** and **C**.
Are there any methods or classes dedicated for this?

Especialy I need to get XML structure and values of node `<default>` so that I can restore default values of system configuration of modules B and C. Below is example from config.xml of Wishlist module:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <wishlist>
            <general>
                <active>1</active>
            </general>
            <email>
                <email_identity>general</email_identity>
                <email_template>wishlist_email_email_template</email_template>
            </email>
        </wishlist>
    </default>
</config>
```

As far as I know Magento loads config.xml files of all modules, so I was wondering maybe this data is already cached and can be retrieved from cache somehow? If not, how to retrieve it programaticaly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get a certain node from the config like this.

```
$value = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/wishlist/general/active');
```

this should retrive the value of

```
<default>
    <wishlist>
        <general>
            <active>1</active> <!-- this value -->
        </general>
    </wishlist>
</default>
```

The problem is that it does not retrieve the value from a specific file. it gets the value from the merged config.

If you want values from a specific file, do this.

```
$configFile = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleDir('etc', 'Mage_Wishlist').DS.'config.xml';
$string = file_get_contents($configFile);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, 'Varien_Simplexml_Element');
```

You will have in the `$xml` variable the loaded xml file and your can use `xpath` to find a specific node.

Comment: The value could be retrieved from the DB if it is defined in the column `path` in `core_config_data`, too. But only in the XML's config files (this are the defaults)

Answer (score 6):

You can access the `config.xml` of any module through `Mage::getConfig`. All XMLs are merged into one string so you can't really specify the exact module but you can filter on tags path.

```
$default_xml = Mage::getConfig()
   ->loadModulesConfiguration('config.xml')
   ->getNode('default/wishlist')
   ->asXML();
```

You might need to add a dependency in module **A** on module **B** and **C** to make sure their `config.xml` is loaded when you're executing above code.